# Quadratic programming with the non-negativity constraint

Tags: matrix-calculus, quadratic-programming

Let us assume that $B$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$. What is the optimum solution for the following constrained quadratic programming problem:
$$min_{X>=0}\,\,trace(X^TBX).$$
Here, it should be mentioned that X is a non-negative matrix.

Moreover, if we assume that $X$ is a non-negative diagonal matrix, how can we solve this problem with this new constraint?

**P.S.: In both cases, I guess that the solution is the zero matrix, which minimizes the objective function subject to the specified constraints.**

Comment: It seems you've answered your own question.  The zero matrix satisfies your constraints.  The only part left to prove is that it is minimal.  That's true because $B$ is psd, so it can be written as $B = A^TA$ for some $A$. Then $X^TBX = (AX)^TAX$ is also psd, so has trace $\geq 0$.  So, the choice of $X = 0$ satisfies the constraints and gives a trace of $0$.